# Is possible to set default arg for a rest variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is possible to set default arg for a rest variable in JavaScript? Something like:

```
function(first,...second=[arg1,arg2]){

}
```

Comment: Are you using ES5 or ES6?

Comment: Thanks for reply ,  ES6

Answer (score 3):

No, that’s not possible, but also not hard to work around:

```
function (first, ...second) {
    if (second.length === 0) {
        second = [arg1, arg2];
    }
}
```